# how to pass the JTable values to one Frame to another

Tags: java

I am creating a simple inventory system in java. I like to pass data into one JFrame to another. only one data I can pass. I don't how to pass multiple data. what I tried to far attach below.

this how to create a model

```
DefaultTableModel dtm;
        dtm.addRow(new Object[]
        { 
            txtproduct.getText(),
            txtprice.getText(),

        });
```

Comment: You are having two similar constructor `public print(String name)` and `public print(String age)` which are the same. Compiler doesn't care about the name of arguments. It's only care about the type and number of argument. So both your constructors are exactly the same as `public print(String s)` which is an error. Try to merge them into one constructor like this: `public print(String name, String age)`

Comment: i tried what you said but at  this point i am getting an error  age.setText(age); i cannot write the second Jtextbox name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cant have two constructors with the same params

Try to do this:

```
public print(String user, String age)
{
    initComponents();
    this.lname = user;
    this.lage = age;
    name.setText(lname);
    age.setText(lage);
}
```

And then pass "", where you dont want some of the params.
Create the JFrame

```
new print(name, "").setVisible(true);
```

or

```
new print("", age).setVisible(true);
```

Comment: sir only one data displayed   public print(String user, String age)
{
    initComponents();
    this.lname = user;
    this.lage = age;
    txtname.setText(lname);
    txtage.setText(lage);
}

Comment: txtage.setText(lage); here no data displayed sir no error displayed now

Comment: what params are you using? is lage null or empty?

Comment: new print(name, "").setVisible(true);
        new print("", age).setVisible(true);        empty sir only age displayed name didn't displayed

Comment: and using `new print(name, age).setVisible(true);` name and age are displayed??

Comment: one value can received in this function sir public print(String user, String age)

Comment: sir how to pass jTable records to another frame any idea

Comment: Ok. Yes, you can pass the `new print(jTable.getModel())` and in your constructor you can change to `print(TableModel model) { jTable.setModel(model) } `

Comment: please help on this sir

Comment: DefaultTableModel dtm;
        dtm.addRow(new Object[]
        { 
            txtproduct.getText(),
            txtprice.getText(),
           
        });

Comment: have you get the model from jTable?  `DefaultTableModel dtm = (DefaultTableModel) jTable.getModel()`

Comment: yes. in my my jTable consist of two columns product and  price. i  will attached screen shot sir. i call to send frame to print